# Adding a hash to an array

Tags: arrays, perl, multidimensional-array, hashtable

I have an array like so:

```
@switch_ports = ()
```

and then want to add 50 instances of this hash, to the switch_ports array.

```
%port = (data1 => 0, data2 => 0, changed => 0)
```

However, if I push my hash to the array:

```
push(@switch_ports, %port)
```

and I do `print @switch_ports`, I just see:

```
data10data20changed0
```

so it just seems to be adding them to the array, (joining them)
and if I try and loop the array and print the keys, it also fails.

1. Can you store a hash in an array?
2. Can you have an array of hashes?

I'm trying to get this:

```
switchports
    0
        data1
        data2
        changed
    1
        data1
        ....
```

thus:

```
foreach $port (@switchport) {
    print $port['data1']
}
```

would return all of the data1 for all of the hashes in the array.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

In Perl, array and hash members must be a single value. Before Perl 5.0, there was no (easy) way to do what you want.

However, in Perl 5 you can now use a reference to your hash. A reference is simply the memory location where the item is being stored. To get a reference, you put a backslash in front of the variable:

```
use feature qw(say);

my $foo = "bar";
say $foo;    #prints "bar"
say \$foo;   #prints SCALAR(0x7fad01029070) or something like that
```

Thus:

```
my @switch_ports = ();
my %port = ( data1 => 0, data2 => 0, changed => 0 );
my $port_ref = \%port;

push( @switch_ports, $port_ref );
```

And, you don't have to create `$port_ref`:

```
my @switch_ports = ();
my %port = ( data1 => 0, data2 => 0, changed => 0 );

push( @switch_ports, \%port );
```

To get the actual value of the reference, simply put the symbol back on front:

```
#Remember: This is a REFERENCE to the hash and not the hash itself
$port_ref = $switch_ports[0];
%port = %{$port_ref};      #Dereferences the reference $port_ref;

print "$port{data1}  $port{data2}  $port{changed}\n";
```

Another shortcut:

```
%port = %{$port[0]};   #Dereference in a single step
print "$port{data1}  $port{data2}  $port{changed}\n";
```

Or, even shorter, dereferencing as you go along:

```
print ${$port[0]}{data1} . " " . ${$port[0]}{data2} . " " . ${$port[0]}{changed} . "\n";
```

And a little syntactic sweetener. It means the same, but is easier to read:

```
print $port[0]->{data1} . " " . $port[0]->{data2} . " " . $port[0]->{changed} . "\n";
```

Take a look at Perldoc's [perlreftut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html) and [perlref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html). The first one is a tutorial.

Comment: Perl 5.000 was released on October 17, 1994. I think that by 2011, 17 years later, disclaimers about Perl4 behavior are no longer very necessary :)

Comment: You'd think this would be the case. However, there's a lot of Perl tutorials out there still stuck in ancient Perl 3.x syntax: _If it was good enough for Grandpa, it's good enough for me!_. I still see people using `require "find.pl";` instead of `use File::Find;` and `chop` instead of `chomp`. Even many modern _Learn Perl_ books never get into references.

Answer (score 11):

When you try:

```
%port = (data1 => 0, data2 => 0, changed => 0);
push @switch_ports, %port;
```

What really happens is:

```
push @switch_ports, "data1", 0, "data2", 0, "changed", 0;
```

Because arrays and hashes will [automatically break into their elements](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#List-value-constructors) when used in list context.

When you want to create 50 instances of a hash, it is not a good idea to use a reference to an existing hash as others have suggested, as that will only create 50 different references to the *same* hash. Which will crash and burn for obvious reasons.

What you need is something like:

```
push @array, { data1 => 0, data2 => 0, changed => 0 } for 1 .. 50;
```

Which will add 50 unique anonymous hashes to the array. The braces denotes construction of an anonymous hash, and returns a scalar reference to it.

ETA: Your example of how to access this data is wrong.

```
foreach $port (@switchport) {
    print $port['data1'];    # will use @port, not $port
}
```

Using a subscript on a scalar variable will attempt to access an *array* in that namespace, not a scalar. In perl, it is valid to have two separate variables `$port` and `@port`. Brackets are used for arrays, not hashes. When using references, you also need to use the arrow operator: `$port->{data1}`. Hence:

```
for my $port (@switchport) {
    print $port->{data1};
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can store a *reference to* a hash in an array:

```
push @switchport, \%port; # stores a reference to your existing hash
```

or

```
push @switchport, { %port }; # clones the hash so it can be updated separately
```

Then iterate with, say,

```
foreach my $port (@switchport) {
    print $port->{'data1'}; # or $$port{'data1'}
}
```

See `man perlref`.

Answer (score 4):

To simplify for those who use this question to find a general approach - as in the Heading Question. Mysql theme:

```
my @my_hashes = ();
my @$rows = ... # Initialize. Mysql SELECT query results, for example.

if( @$rows ) {
    foreach $row ( @$rows ) { # Every row to hash, every hash to an array.
        push @my_hashes, { 
            id => $row->{ id }, 
            name => $row->{ name }, 
            value => $row->{ value }, 
        };
    }
}
```

To loop and print out:

```
for my $i ( 0 .. $#my_hashes ) {
    print "$my_hashes[$i]{ id }\n ";
    print "$my_hashes[$i]{ name }\n ";
    print "$my_hashes[$i]{ value }\n ";
}
```

or

```
for my $i ( 0 .. $#my_hashes ) {
for my $type ( keys %{ $my_hashes[$i] } ) {
     print "$type=$my_hashes[$i]{$type} ";
}
```

}